# Joomla website - content displays for registered users but not for regular visitors

Tags: joomla

I have to do fix some bugs on a Joomla website that I didn't build. Also, I don't know Joomla. Biggest issue at the moment is that the content displays for registered users but not for regular visitors. The website in question is http://johngilesfoundation.com/

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be nearly impossible to say definitely without knowing what is supposed to display, and what is actually displaying and the extensions that are installed. Joomla 1.5 has a rudimentary access control that could be your issue. In virtually everything - menus, modules, articles, etc - you have the ability to set the Access Level. It is usually on the left side of the details page and the options should be Public, Registered, and Special. Make sure that all of these are set to public.

Comment: Found the issue. Problem was that I had set caching on, but no write access to the caching folder. I set every directory that I had to writable, turned cache off and now it works.

Comment: Make sure that files are set to 644 and folders are set to 755.

Comment: I know that's advisable and the normal, safe way to do. But the back-end administration area spits errors all over the place when they're set like that :( More specifically, it says it can't save the changes, don't recall the exact error message but it's not a PHP error, it's an error from the CMS. Personally, first impression on Joomla isn't the best that I could have, but I have no choice. Any advices?

Comment: You can check directory permissions by going to ADMIN > Help > System Info > Directory Permissions. If setting a directory to 755 doesn't result in the directory being writable then I would look toward your server setup. Most common, you need to make sure that Apache is running in CGI Mode instead of as a module. Your host should be able to help with that.